# Getting data from mongodb and showing them in map() function not workign properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

so i have some food order commands that i stored in my database (im using mongodb)

[image]

and here i have this interface where i can display the data from data base and show them :

```js
export default class Panier extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            CmdCart:[]

        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("http://10.0.2.2:4000/getcmd", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((results) => {
                try {

                    this.setState({ CmdCart: results })
                    console.log("food order data:", JSON.stringify(this.state.CmdCart))

                } catch (e) {

                    console.log(e)
                }
            })
    }
    render() {

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>

                {
                    this.state.CmdCart.map((item, i) => {

                        return (
                            <View style={{ flex: 1, }} key={i}>

                                <View style={{ width: width - 20, margin: 10, backgroundColor: 'transparent', flexDirection: 'row', borderBottomWidth: 2, borderColor: "#cccccc", paddingBottom: 10 }}>
                                    
                                    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'transparent', padding: 10, justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
                                        <View>
                                            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                                                <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: 20 }}>ID :  {item._id}</Text>

                                            </View>
                                            <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: 20 }}>Choix :  {item.choix}</Text>
                                            <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: 20 }}>Data :  {item.data.Sauce},{item.data.Viande}</Text>
                                            
                                            
                                        </View>
                                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                                            <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 20 }}>Date :{item.date}</Text>
                                            
                                            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>

                                                

                                            </View>
                                        </View>
                                    </View>
                                </View>

                            </View>
                            
                            );

                    })
                }
            </View>




            );
        }
    }
```

i noticed i can only get few items from my map() function except the 'Data' which is shown as blank here :

[image]

here is my log console :

[image]

they appear as undefined

```
console.log("data Sauce", item.data.Sauce , 'Data Viande : ',item.data.Viande)
```

[image]

is there any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

item.data is also an array so using item.data.map() should do the trick.

```
<Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: 20 }}>
  Data : {item.data.map((elem) => elem.Sauce)},
  {item.data.map((elem) => elem.Viande)}
</Text>
```

If the length of item.data is one always, then simply use

```
<Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: 20 }}>
  Data : {item.data[0].Sauce)}, {item.data[0].Viande)}
</Text>
```

This should give you the result as

```
Data : [" Viande hachee"], [" Algerienne"]
```